# What Is The Best Way to Implement Entity-Component System

Tags: json, go, serialization, marshalling

Recently I am planing to implement a  [Entity-Component-System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) like Overwatch.

The major challenge(and difficulty) in my project is that, my engine allows user defined customized map, in which user was allowed to define customized unit. In another word, **user can select which component they need for an entity type**

For example

```
type Component interface {
    ComponentName() string
}

type HealthComponent struct {
    HP uint
}

type ManaComponent struct {
    MP uint
}

type ChiComponent struct{
        Chi uint
}
// assuming each component has implemented Component interface
```

The corresponding Entity definition is:

```
type Entity struct {
    ID         EID
    EntityName string
    Components map[string]Component
}
```

A user will have some entity definition in JSON format:

```
{
 "EntityName": "FootMan",
 "Components": {
  "HealthComponent": {
   "HP": 500
  }
 }
}
---------------------------------------------
{
 "EntityName": "Warlock",
 "Components": {
  "HealthComponent": {
   "HP": 250
  },
  "ManaComponent": {
   "MP": 100
  }
 }
}
---------------------------------------------
{
 "EntityName": "Monk",
 "Components": {
  "HealthComponent": {
   "HP": 250
  },
  "ChiComponent": {
   "Chi": 100
  }
 }
}
```

Please notice that ID is not included in JSON because we need to initialize it at run-time

So here comes the problem:
**What is the most efficient way to build such an entity with a given JSON definition?**
Currently my solution is using a registry to maintain a map between struct type and component name

```
var componentRegistry = make(map[string]reflect.Type)
func init() {

    componentRegistry["ChiComponent"] = reflect.TypeOf(ChiComponent{})
    componentRegistry["HealthComponent"] = reflect.TypeOf(HealthComponent{})
    componentRegistry["ManaComponent"] = reflect.TypeOf(ManaComponent{})

}
```

The builder code is

```
func ComponentBuilder(name string) Component {

    v := reflect.New(componentRegistry[name])
    fmt.Println(v)
    return v.Interface().(Component)
}

func EntityBuilder(EntityName string, RequireComponent []string) *Entity {

    var entity = new(Entity)
    entity.ID = getNextAvailableID()
    entity.EntityName = EntityName
    entity.Components = make(map[string]Component)
    for _, v := range RequireComponent {
        entity.Components[v] = ComponentBuilder(v)
    }

    return entity
}
```

For each system that want to access a component in this entity needs to do following:

```
var d = monk_entity.Components["ChiComponent"].(*ChiComponent)
d.Chi = 13

var h = monk_entity.Components["HealthComponent"].(*HealthComponent)
h.HP = 313
```

It works, but I am using too much reflection in this approach and I am not able to assign initial value to entity, which was store in user defined JSON file. Is there any better way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gor one thing, you can just use functions instead of reflection:

```
type componentMaker func() Component  // Define generator signature

var componentRegistry = make(map[string]componentMaker) // Update map type

componentRegistry["ChiComponent"] = func() Component { return new(ChiComponent) } // Define generators

entity.Components[v] = componentRegistry[v]() // Call generator
```

And so on. No reflection needed.